# How to select all results tied for first position

Tags: mysql, select

My current output is a list of caretakers and how many budgies they take care of. I get it via the following SELECT statement:

```
SELECT caretakers.name, COUNT(species.name) 
FROM caretakers
JOIN cares_for ON cares_for.caretaker=caretakers.id
JOIN animals ON cares_for.animal=animals.id
JOIN species ON animals.species=species.id
WHERE species.name LIKE 'budgie'
GROUP BY caretakers.name
ORDER BY COUNT(species.name) DESC
```

- `Animals` is a table containing specific distinct animals and their names.
- `Species` is a table containing species with id tags to which 'animals can link to (via `animals.species`)'.
- `Caretakers` is a table containing specific distinct people and their names
- `Cares_for` is a table containing ids of specific animals that are being cared for and the `id` of the specific caretaker that cares for them.

My current output is 33 rows, all but 2 of which only take care of 1 budgie. The two others each take care of 2 budgies.

How would I make it so that only the caretakers tied for the first place get displayed? I've tried using `MAX(Count(...))` in various places, even restructuring `WHERE` to `HAVING`, but everything returns an error.

Help would be welcome.

Comment: Version of MySQL?

Comment: You have a typo: `FROM caretakers
JOIN caretakers` should be `FROM caretakers
JOIN cares_for`

Comment: *only the caretakers tied for the first place get displayed?* What is "place"? some field in some table? Some statistic based on some data from this tables? Try to create adequate source sample and desired output with it... maybe as a fiddle.

Comment: See the tag I added; there are solutions there or [_here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).